# csrf token issue from Vuex to Django API backend

Tags: vue.js

how to pass csrf token from vuex axios to Django API using a global interceptor in vuex. Currently, I am passing csrf with each post, put and delete request like

```
putResponseResults: function (context, postData) {
      axios.post('/api/responses/', postData,  { headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': Cookie.get('csrftoken')} })
        .then(function (response) {
          // console.log(response.data)
        })
```

Is there any global way to pass csrf token using vuex, so I don't need to write it every time.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a CSRF token as a default header (so that it will be attached to every subsequent request) as follows:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRFToken'] = 'your token';
```

More information on axios config defaults can be found in [axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#config-defaults).

Comment: Thanks for the help, It's working fine. Now I don't need to pass it with every request

Comment: @SachinGadhari You are very welcome! Please accept the answer if you find it helpful, thanks.